# Change marquee direction on scroll without changing its current position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `marquee.js` jQuery plugin to render a list in a text scroller, but what I'm trying to do is change the direction of the scrolling text when clicking the buttons without changing the current position of the text.

Here is what I have tried:

```js
var direction = 'left';

$('.right-scroll').on('click', function() {
  direction = 'right'
})

$('.left-scroll').on('click', function() {
  direction = 'left'
})

$(function() {
  $('.scrollermarquee').marquee({
    duration: 15000,
    direction: direction
  });
});
```

```css
.scrollermarquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: black;
  color: rgb(202, 255, 195);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

<button class="left-scroll">Left scroll</button>
<button class="right-scroll">Right scroll</button>

<div class="scrollermarquee">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content">
          <a href="/node/805" hreflang="en">test1</a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content">
          <a href="/node/801" hreflang="en">test2</a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="views-field views-field-title">
        <span class="field-content">
          <a href="/node/470" hreflang="en">test3</a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please check from this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023699/how-to-change-direction-of-marquee-onclick-immediately

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `direction` variable in the `click` event handlers but not calling any code to update the configuration of `$('.scrollermarquee')`.

```
<script>

    // set marquee to scroll in supplied direction
    var setMarquee = function(direction) {
       $('.scrollermarquee').marquee({
            duration: 15000,
            direction: direction
        });
    };

    $('.right-scroll').on('click',function(){
        setMarquee('right'); // change marquee direction to right
    })

    $('.left-scroll').on('click',function(){
        setMarquee('left'); // change marquee direction to left
    })

    $(function () {
        setMarquee('left'); // start marquee when page loads
    });

</script>
```